# Working examples of 'Locust_plugins' webdriverex.py

Tags: selenium-webdriver, locust

I'm really interested running load tests with locust/selenium. I saw some real promising results using the older framework 'realbrowserlocusts' but I'm having an issues getting the locust_plugins to run on Windows.
Do you have any projects in Github that would run on windows. I've started the Selenium server and have the chromedriver in the right place.

Here's the call stack:

(venv) C:\Users\localuser\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\locust-plugins\examples>locust -f cyberw_test.py
[2021-05-28 11:24:51,348] LHTU05CD943125T/INFO/locust.main: Starting web interface at http://0.0.0.0:8089 (accepting connections from all network interfaces)
[2021-05-28 11:24:51,356] LHTU05CD943125T/INFO/locust.main: Starting Locust 1.4.3
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "src\gevent\greenlet.py", line 906, in gevent._gevent_cgreenlet.Greenlet.run
File "c:\users\localuser\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\locust\web.py", line 339, in start_server
self.server.serve_forever()
File "c:\users\localuser\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\gevent\baseserver.py", line 398, in serve_forever
self.start()
File "c:\users\localuser\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\gevent\baseserver.py", line 336, in start
self.init_socket()
File "c:\users\localuser\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\gevent\pywsgi.py", line 1545, in init_socket
StreamServer.init_socket(self)
File "c:\users\localuser\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\gevent\server.py", line 180, in init_socket
self.socket = self.get_listener(self.address, self.backlog, self.family)
File "c:\users\localuser\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\gevent\server.py", line 192, in get_listener
return _tcp_listener(address, backlog=backlog, reuse_addr=cls.reuse_addr, family=family)
File "c:\users\localuser\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\gevent\server.py", line 288, in _tcp_listener
sock.bind(address)
File "c:\users\localuser\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\gevent_socketcommon.py", line 563, in bind
return self._sock.bind(address)
OSError: [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted: ('', 8089)
2021-05-28T17:24:51Z <Greenlet at 0x4f5c820: <bound method WebUI.start_server of <locust.web.WebUI object at 0x04F98130>>> failed with OSError

### [2021-05-28 11:24:51,388] LHTU05CD943125T/CRITICAL/locust.web: Unhandled exception in greenlet: <Greenlet at 0x4f5c820: <bound method WebUI.start_server of <locust.web.WebUI object at 0x0
4F98130>>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "src\gevent\greenlet.py", line 906, in gevent._gevent_cgreenlet.Greenlet.run
File "c:\users\localuser\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\locust\web.py", line 339, in start_server
self.server.serve_forever()
File "c:\users\localuser\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\gevent\baseserver.py", line 398, in serve_forever
self.start()
File "c:\users\localuser\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\gevent\baseserver.py", line 336, in start
self.init_socket()
File "c:\users\localuser\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\gevent\pywsgi.py", line 1545, in init_socket
StreamServer.init_socket(self)
File "c:\users\localuser\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\gevent\server.py", line 180, in init_socket
self.socket = self.get_listener(self.address, self.backlog, self.family)
File "c:\users\localuser\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\gevent\server.py", line 192, in get_listener
return _tcp_listener(address, backlog=backlog, reuse_addr=cls.reuse_addr, family=family)
File "c:\users\localuser\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\gevent\server.py", line 288, in _tcp_listener
sock.bind(address)
File "c:\users\localuser\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\gevent_socketcommon.py", line 563, in bind
return self._sock.bind(address)
OSError: [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted: ('', 8089)
[2021-05-28 11:24:51,389] LHTU05CD943125T/INFO/locust.main: Running teardowns...
[2021-05-28 11:24:51,390] LHTU05CD943125T/INFO/locust.main: Shutting down (exit code 2), bye.
[2021-05-28 11:24:51,390] LHTU05CD943125T/INFO/locust.main: Cleaning up runner...
Name                                                          # reqs      # fails  |     Avg     Min     Max  Median  |   req/s failures/s

---

Aggregated                                                         0     0(0.00%)  |       0       0       0       0  |    0.00    0.00

Response time percentiles (approximated)
Type     Name                                                              50%    66%    75%    80%    90%    95%    98%    99%  99.9% 99.99%   100% # reqs
--------|------------------------------------------------------------|---------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|
--------|------------------------------------------------------------|---------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the underlying problem:

OSError: [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted: ('', 8089)

Make sure you dont have some previously started instance of Locust running.

locust-plugins is mainly built/tested for linux/macOS so you may run in to other issues as well, but this issue seems to be a pure locust issue.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 10 users wanting to run with locust-plugins, especially the webdriver.py.
It took a combination of the right versions of a few things to get it running. In running in secure environments there are additional roadblocks that you need to work-around. If you install with this list of software versions you'll be all setup to run.
Many thanks to Cyberwiz for his help.

[image]